# Angular | Router won't redirect

Tags: angular, redirect, angular-routing, router

I have implemented the following code to redirect to my Greenhouse Plants

```
    <div *ngFor="let plant of plants" (click)="openPlant(plant)">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 p-l-0 p-r-0 my-auto">
                <img src="..." class="navbar-item-icon">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9 my-auto">
                {{plant.englishName}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

(click) openPlant:

```
  public openPlant(plant: PlantModel) {
    var foundPoor = this.checkIfPlantIsPoor(plant),
    this._generalService.openPlant(foundPoor, plant)
  }
```

_generalService openPlant:

```
  public openPlant(foundPoor, plant: PlantModel) {
    if (foundPoor) {
        ...
    } else {
        this.router.navigate(['desktop/plant/' + plant.id]);
    }
  }
```

So, when I click to a plant, it will redirect just fine. But after it redirects to the first plant, when i click to others, the url in the browser is changing but it wont redirect to the actual route! It is just sstaying to the first plant I clicked.

So the first time it goes to http://localhost:4200/desktop/plant/2, then I click to redirect to http://localhost:4200/desktop/crop/11, the url in the browser changes to http://localhost:4200/desktop/crop/11 but the UI stays on http://localhost:4200/desktop/plant/2

Here is my app.routing

```
const routes: Routes = [
  ...
  { path: 'desktop', loadChildren: () => import('./pages/desktop/desktop.module').then(m => m.DesktopModule) },
  ...
];
```

Here is desktop.routing:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  ...
  { path: 'plant/:id', component: PlantComponent},
  ...
];
```

Here is PlantComponent:

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <plant-item [plantID]=plantID></crop>
</div>
```

TS

```
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.plantID)
    var _this = this
    var route = this.router.url
    this.plantID = this.activated_route.snapshot.paramMap.get("id")
  }
```

Here is PlantItemComponent TS:

```
    ...
    this._plantService.currentPlants.subscribe(res => {
      this.activeSeed = this._plantsService.getMyActiveSeed(res, this.plantID)
      ...      
    })
```

on ngOnInit it will console.log only the first time i navigate to the first Plant. When I click to navigate to ther others it wont console.log.

Here is a stackblitz focusing on the routing and how i call needed components: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c9g1hl

Comment: Can you share your route definitions

Comment: Please share a Stackblitz to track down your error.

Comment: @RahulTokase updated my answer with more code and a stackblitz. Thank you foryour time!

Answer (score 1):

Problem here is that when you navigate to the same route, even with a different param, Angular reutilizes the component instance. That means that your `ngOnInit` function is getting called only once. I think the simplest way of solving this is handling `ActivatedRoute` as an observable:

```
ngOnInit() {
  console.log(this.plantID)
  var _this = this
  var route = this.router.url

  this.activated_route.params.subscribe(params => {
    this.plantID = params.id;
  });
}
```

Comment: Yeah I already did that, was hoping for a better solution but it works anyway. Thanks for your effort though :D